# Mallet Natural Language Processing Mallet

Tags: nlp, mallet

I am trying to learn MALLET developed by UMASS Amhrest. I am pretty new to this and hence this may be a silly question.

I just ran a sample example given on their website using following command.

```
bin/mallet import-dir --input sample-data/web/* --output web.mallet
```

Now, I have the web.mallet output file and I dont know how to open it.
I am using Linux and gedit cant read this file.

How can I open the output file and see its contents?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

The file `web.mallet` is not intended to be human-readable. It is meant as an input for further processing with MALLET.

Once you have the file `web.mallet` you can apply `bin/mallet train-topics` to it. There are some MALLET tutorials out there on the web, look at, e.g., http://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/kwsearch/MALLET/0/ or try your favorite search engine.

Comment: I've asked a question related to ",mallet" files here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252362/what-are-the-memory-limitation-for-mallet-training-files