# What are the memory limitation for Mallet training files?

Tags: mallet

Mallet converts training cases to binary format using the command import-file, e.g.

bin/mallet import-file --input cases.txt --output cases.mallet

How is this binary ".mallet" file then used?  Is it streamed or is the whole file loaded into memory.  If it is all loaded then this places a limit on the number of training cases based on available memory.

Is it possible to characterize the size of the .mallet file based on the the size of input cases file or number of input cases?

Comment: I don't know how it is processed & how size can be determined on the basis on input cases but in mallet batch file( available inside bin folder of mallet download ) size allocated to JVM is fixed to 1G. If you are getting memory error & more memory space is available then you can just increase this default limit by editing it as per your requirement & available memory. More details can be found at http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet  "Issues with Big Data section".